Samba not working after migrating to a new machine
I had a sambashare working fine on Lubuntu, but my old computer broke down.
I moved the SSD to a new computer. Everything works fine except for the sambashare. Of course, when asking for status, I now point to the new IP. Status returns:
        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        sambashare      Disk      Samba on Ubuntu
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (kuyper-belt server (Samba, Ubuntu))
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available


Why the new IP? Can't the new computer have the same IP as old one?

Good point. I will assign the old IP to the new computer.

You've provided no Lubuntu release details; we're somewhat limited in being help due to not actually knowing what you're running (you've not said the release detail which provides software stack age & details!)
